# Saturated blue image in MJPG streaming with a Raspberry Pi and a webcam

Tags: raspbian, camera, streaming

I compiled `mjpeg_streamer` and it works correctly with my laptop's webcam (`/dev/video0`). But if I use my usb webcam (a4tech) it shows the stream like this:

[image]

The command is as follows:

```
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_uvc.so -d /dev/video1 -y -f 5 -n -r 320x240" -o "./output_http.so -w ./www"
```

Terminal output is this:

```
MJPG Streamer Version: svn rev: 3:172
 i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video1
 i: Desired Resolution: 320 x 240
 i: Frames Per Second.: 5
 i: Format............: YUV
 i: JPEG Quality......: 80
 o: www-folder-path...: ./www/
 o: HTTP TCP port.....: 8080
 o: username:password.: disabled
 o: commands..........: enabled
```

The usb webcam works correctly if I open it via VLC or FFMPEG. Is there any configuration necessary to make for YUV driver?